# Find the group id of chat group from user ids that are part of group mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I am developing a chat application.

I can find the group id if group contains only two people with the given sql query.

My db structure is (userId and groupId are foreign keys):

```
Group: 
id | name | createdAt 
1    foo 
2    boo

GroupUser:

userId | groupId | createdAt

1        1
2        1
3        1

select guf.groupId 
from GroupUser guf 
INNER join GroupUser gu 
    on guf.groupId = gu.groupId 
where guf.userId = 1 
and gu.userId != guf.userId 
and EXISTS (
    select gu.groupId 
    from GroupUser 
    where gu.userId = 2
)
```

Currently i can't find group id of conversation which includes at least 3 or more people. To be more specific for example group contains 4 people. Based on their ids i want to find group id. Like what is the group id that given 4 specific people in it ? It must return for example 1(which is groupId).

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: question updated.

Comment: What exactly you want is still unclear. Your written script returning GroupId 1 that has 3 users in the chat group. And as per your question, I feel this is the requirement :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want groups that contain three people:

```
select gu.group_id
from groupusers gu
where gu.user_id in (1, 2, 3)
group by gu.group_id
having count(*) = 3;
```

If you want exactly three people, you can move the condition to the `having` clause:

```
select gu.group_id
from groupusers gu
group by gu.group_id
having sum(gu.user_id in (1, 2, 3)) = 3;
```

As written, these queries assume that `groupusers` does not have duplicate rows.  That seems like a reasonable assumption.  The logic could be tweaked to use `count(distinct)` if duplicates are allowed.

Comment: @MertDoe. . . The second query answers this question.